# I need something in c# which work like the setw() in c++

Tags: c#, alignment, formatting, setw

I am using a richTextBox in c#. I need to display strings of different length inside one richTextBox but these strings should be perfectly aligned.. this is an example..

```
abcd   abcde  abcde
ab     abc    abcdef
```

I know how to do this in c++ using the setw function.. but I could not find an equivalent in c#.

Comment: `String.PadRight(int maxLen)`?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it was this easy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do use [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
innerString.PadRight(10);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
string varName=String.Format("{0,10:D}", 2);
```

This will format number 2 as a string of width 10 aligned right, use -5 to have it aligned left in the width of 5...

Source : http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100727164827AAqJ1Hn

Answer (score 0):

I created a function for that purpose:

```
public string tab(string s, int w)
{
    //w is the desired width
    int stringwidth = s.Length;
    int i;
    string resultstring = s;

    for(i=0;i<=(w-stringwidth)/8;i++)
    {
        resultstring = resultstring + "\t";
    }
    return resultstring;
 }
```

Then, adding it to a ListBox, for example:

```
listBox.Items.Add(tab("MyFullNameHere",30)+ tab("MyContact - xxxxx",12));
listBox.Items.Add(tab("MyWifeFullNameHereVeryLong", 30) + tab("HerContact - xxxxx", 12));
```